# MongoDB change streams: using watch filters to get data updates

Tags: mongodb, stream

I need to be able to make a query with filter, then watch for data changes (similar to RethinkDB's changefeeds).

The problem is, when some documents gets updated and doesn't satisfy the filter condition because of that change I'm not getting it in the change stream, so I cannot remove it from my data snapshot.

e.g., watching for documents with val=1

```
watchCursor = db.test.watch([{$match: {"fullDocument.val":1}}], { fullDocument : "updateLookup" })
while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
    if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      printjson(watchCursor.next());
   }
}
```

inserting matching document(here I get change stream update):

`db.test.insertOne({id:1, val:1})`

then updating the document:

`db.test.updateOne({id:1}, {$set: {val:2}})`

and no update in change stream, so I cannot update my data snapshot and remove the document which no more matches the filter.

I know this is expected behaviour, as change streams are based on oplog, but is there a solution to achieve the RethinkDB's changefeed behaviour with MongoDB change streams ?

Comment: I have the same issue with documents being deleted.  Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really. In my case deletions were not frequent, so I subscribed a change stream of **all** deleted documents and just filtered it in app code.